# \textbf and \bf within Sans Serif

Tags: font-encodings, sans-serif

I'm using `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` so that my entire document is in sans serif, but I'm getting peculiar results with regards to formatting.

I'm a rather sparse LaTeX user, but in the past I've always used `\textbf{Super Important Text!}` for bold text rather than what I've been told is obsolete; `{\bf Important Junk}` (which is what I first learned).

While I have that `\sfdefault` line in the preamble, `\textbf{}` is completely ignored while `{\bf }` is not. I suppose it wouldn't be the end of the world if the answer is that I just have to use `{\bf }`, but I'm assuming there's a reason you're not supposed to.

The closest solution I could find was [Bold sans-serif font in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48782/bold-sans-serif-font-in-latex), but it dealt with section names rather than in text formatting.

**EDIT**: My apologies - after recreating the document bit by bit, it turns out `\usepackage{charter}` was causing this. The confusing part was that *if* I removed `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`, then normal boldface functionality was restored. It turns out `\textbf` wouldn't work iff both lines were in the preamble. Although I'm curious to know why this is, I don't need `charter` for the project I'm currently working on, so for practical purposes this issue has been resolved.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{charter}                             % If either of these two are removed
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % There is no issue

\begin{document}
\textbf{Not bold.}
{\bf Quite Bold.}
Also Not Bold.
\end{document}
```

Not Bold. **Quite Bold.** Also Not Bold.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! My test tells me that `\textbf` is obeyed. Can you show a minimal example of code producing the issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The root of the problem is a bit of a naming problem: Computer Modern's bold series is actually bold/extended, code bx, while most other fonts have an ordinary bold, code b. Your log file should tell you something like:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmss/m/n' instead on input line 6.
```

which translated to something readable means: "I don't have Computer Modern Sans in Bold Upright, so I'm using Computer Modern Sans in Medium Upright instead". (`charter` redefines bold to mean bold, not bold-extended, so that its boldface works.)

The easiest fix is probably to use `\usepackage{lmodern,charter}` because `lmodern`, while optically pretty identical to the default Computer Modern font, has a b-not-bx-bold for its sans-serif typeface.

Comment: Another possibility is to say `\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{bx}` after loading `charter`, since the font description files for the `bch` family define substitutions from `bx` to `b`. But this is irrelevant if one changes `\familydefault` to mean `\sfdefault`: the easiest fix is to remove the loading of `charter`, which becomes useless.

Comment: Thanks - this is helpful. I recently switched to TexWorks (Mac), which by default automatically hides the output console unless there's an error, which is why I wasn't seeing this warning.

Answer (score 4):

It is always helpful to supply a complete small document that shows the problem. If I try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\showoutput
aaa \textbf{bbb} {\bf ccc}

\end{document}
```

Then the log (and the pdf result) show that both bbb and ccc are bold sans serif, using the same font:

```
....\OT1/cmss/m/n/10 a
....\OT1/cmss/m/n/10 a
....\OT1/cmss/m/n/10 a
....\kern 0.0
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\OT1/cmss/bx/n/10 b
....\OT1/cmss/bx/n/10 b
....\OT1/cmss/bx/n/10 b
....\kern 0.0
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\OT1/cmss/bx/n/10 c
....\OT1/cmss/bx/n/10 c
....\OT1/cmss/bx/n/10 c
```

[image]